# Mockito mock java function with inner method

Tags: java, function, junit, mockito

I have a class like so:

```
@Component
    public class AddressConverter {

        public Function<Address, AddressDTO> convertToDTO = new Function<Address, AddressDTO>() {
            public AddressDTO apply(Address address) {
                AddressDTO dto = new AddressDTO();
                dto.setAddress1(address.getAddress1());
                dto.setAddress2(address.getAddress2());
                dto.setCity(address.getCity());
                dto.setState(address.getState());
                dto.setZip(address.getZip());
                dto.setZip4(address.getZip4());
                return dto;
            }
        };
}
```

I have another class that uses this like so:

```
     @Component
            public class ProfileConverter {

                @Autowired
                private AddressConverter addressConverter;

                public Function<Profile, ProfileDTO> convertToDTO = new Function<Profile, ProfileDTO>() {
                    public ProfileDTO apply(Profile profile) {
                        ProfileDTO dto = new ProfileDTO();  
        dto.setEmployeeAddress(addressConverter.convertToDTO.apply(profile.getEmployeeAddress()));
return dto;
                    }
                };
    }
```

I am trying to mock the addressConverter class like:

```
EDIT: HERE IS THE TEST CLASS

public class ProfileConverterTest {

    ProfileConverter converter;
    AddressConverter addressConverter;
    Profile profile;
    ProfileDTO dto;
    Address address;
    AddressDTO addressDTO;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        converter = new ProfileConverter();
        addressConverter = Mockito.mock(AddressConverter.class);
        profile = new Profile();
        profile.setProfileId(123L);
        dto = new ProfileDTO();
        Mockito.when(addressConverter.convertFromDTO.apply(addressDTO)).thenReturn(address);
        Mockito.when(addressConverter.convertToDTO.apply(address)).thenReturn(addressDTO);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(converter, "addressConverter", addressConverter);
        address = new Address("1","2","3","4","5","6");
        address.setAddressId(123L);
        addressDTO = new AddressDTO("hash","1","2","3","4","5","6");
    }

    @Test
    public void applyReturnsProfileDTO() throws Exception {
        ProfileDTO result = converter.convertToDTO.apply(profile);
assertEquals(result.getEmployeeAddress().getAddress1(), profile.getEmployeeAddress().getAddress1());
}
}
```

I keep getting a NullPointerException in my test on the first Mockito.when line.  I am thinking it is caused by the mock addressConverter class calling a function calling an inner method.  The function might be null?

Comment: In what line you got NPE? Could you provide your test method as is? More generic question is: why you try to mock a class which is pretty simple?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to know what your test is doing when you leave out all the important parts of it?

Comment: Updated with the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting Mockito to call your class constructor which will initialize the field `convertToDTO`: this is not the case, and the simple test here demonstrate it:

```
  @Test
  public void test_that_yeepee_works() {
    final Yeepee y = Mockito.mock(Yeepee.class);    
    Assertions.assertNotNull(y.myObject); // fails.
  }

  public static class Yeepee {
    public Object myObject = new Object();
  }
```

You might try `Mockito.spy` instead.

Or you need to explicitly do it:

```
converter = new ProfileConverter();
addressConverter = Mockito.mock(AddressConverter.class);
addressConverter.convertToDTO = (Function<Address, AddressDTO>) Mockito.mock(Function.class);
```

If you were using getters, Mockito might have done it for you using smart mocks.

Answer (score 0):

I think, NPE is because you have not created a mock for `AddressConverter` class. You should write something like below:

```
AddressConverter addressConverter = Mockito.mock(AddressConverter.class);
Mockito.when(addressConverter.apply(any(Address.class))).thenReturn(addressDTO);
```

Note: any (`Address.class`) will match any object of `Address` class. If you want to test weather your address object is being used while calling (mocking) apply method, go ahead and add `hashcode()` and `equals()` implementation in your `Address` class.

Comment: Not compilable, `apply()` is belong to Function, not `AddressConverter`.